# Jenkins pipelineJob DSL not interpreting variables in pipeline script

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, pipeline, dsl

I'm trying to generate Jenkins pipelines using the pipelineJob function in the jobDSL pluging, but cannot pass parameters from the DSL to the pipeline script. I have several projects that use what is essentially the same Jenkinsfile, with differences only in a few steps. I'm trying to use the JobDSL plugin to generate these pipelines on the fly, with the values I want changed in them interpreted to match the parameters to the DSL.

I've tried just about every combination of string interpretation that I can in the pipeline script, as well as in the DSL, but cannot get Jenkins/groovy to interpret variables in the pipeline script.

I'm calling the job DSL in a pipeline step:

```
def projectName = "myProject"
def envs = ['DEV','QA','UAT']
def repositoryURL = 'myrepo.com'

jobDsl targets: ['jobs/*.groovy'].join('\n'), 
    additionalParameters: [
        project: projectName, 
        environments: envs, 
        repository: repositoryURL
    ],
    removedJobAction: 'DELETE',
    removedViewAction: 'DELETE'
```

The DSL is as follows:

```
pipelineJob("${project} pipeline") {
    displayName('Pipeline')
        definition {
            cps { 
                script(readFileFromWorkspace(pipeline.groovy))
            }
        }
    }
```

pipeline.groovy:

```
pipeline {
    agent any

    environment {
        REPO = repository
    }

    parameters {
        choice name: "ENVIRONMENT", choices: environments
    }

    stages {
        stage('Deploy') {
            steps {
                echo "Deploying ${env.REPO} to ${params.ENVIRONMENT}..."
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The variables that I pass in additionalParameters are interpreted in the jobDSL script; a pipeline with the correct name does get generated. The problem is that the variables are not passed to the pipeline script read from the workspace - the Jenkins configuration for the generated pipeline looks exactly the same as the file, without any interpretation on the variables.

I've made a number of attempts at getting the string to interpret, including a lot of variations of "${environments}", ${environments}, $environments, \$environments...I can't find any that work. I've also tried reading the file as a gstringImpl:

```
script("${readFileFromWorkspace(pipeline.groovy)}")
```

Does anyone have any ideas as to how I can make variables propagate down to the pipeline script? I know that I could just use a for loop to do string.replaceAll() on the script text, but that seems cumbersome; there's got to be a better way.

Comment: The first thing I notice is you are attempting to access parameter values outside of the `params` map. Try changing to `params.ENVIRONMENT` and see how far that gets you. Additionally you are implicitly accessing `repo` outside of the `env` map, which will be inconsistent for you.

Comment: You were right about accessing parameters outside of the params map - making that change does improve things. The big issue is still there, though; I want the line `choice name: 'ENVIRONMENT' choices: environments` to be interpreted as `choice name: 'ENVIRONMENT' choices: ['DEV', 'QA', 'UAT']` based on the value I'm passing to the job DSL.

Comment: I'm having a similar issue with parameters too. I had to create the parameters at the DSL job description and then again on the pipeline. I think that `cps { script() }` is not interpreted, I think Jenkins just creates the job with the script string as steps and that's it.

Answer (score 3):

I've come up with a way to make this work. It's not what I'd prefer, which is having the string contents of the file implicitly interpreted during job creation, but it does work; it just adds an extra step.

```
import groovy.text.SimpleTemplateEngine

def fileContents = readFileFromWorkspace "pipeline.groovy"

def engine = new SimpleTemplateEngine()
template = engine.createTemplate(fileContents).make(binding.getVariables()).toString()

pipelineJob("${project} pipeline") {
    displayName('Pipeline')
    definition {
        cps { 
            script(template)
        }
    }
}
```

This reads a file from your workspace, then uses it as a template with the binding variables. The other changes needed to make this work are escaping any variables used in your Jenkinsfile script, like `\${VARIABLE}` so that they are expanded at runtime, not at the time you build the job. Any variables you want to be expanded at job creation should be referenced as `${VARIABLE}`.

Answer (score 1):

You could achieve what you're trying to do by defining environment variables in the pipelineJob and then using those variables in your pipeline.

They are a bit limited because environment variables are strings, but it should work for basic stuff

Ex.:

```
//job-dsl
pipelineJob('example') {
    environmentVariables {
        // these vars could be specified by parameters of this job
        env('repository', 'blah')
        env('environments', "a,b,c"]) //comma separated string
    }
    displayName('Pipeline')
        definition {
            cps { 
                script(readFileFromWorkspace(pipeline.groovy))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And then in the pipeline:

```
//pipeline.groovy
pipeline {
    agent any

    environment {
        REPO = env.repository
    }

    parameters {
        choice name: "ENVIRONMENT", choices: env.environments.split(',') 
        //note the need to split the comma separated string above
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the complete job name as a variable without the quotes. E.g., if JOBNAME is a parameter containing the entire job name:

```
pipelineJob(JOBNAME) {
    displayName('Pipeline')
        definition {
            cps { 
                script(readFileFromWorkspace(pipeline.groovy))
            }
        }
    }
```